# unable to remove css of span class due to $(...).css is not a function

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to change the css of a html given a span class.

I have an html as follows:

```
<form id=thing>
   <div id=a>
      <span class=x>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div id=b>
      <span class=x>
      </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

When I inspect the webpage I see the following style being applied:

```
#thing .x {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Now my goal is to get rid of this *display css property* completely.
I tried `$("#thing .x").css("display", "");` but i keep getting `"$(...).css` is not a function - unable to remove css "

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: With the code you've provided I don't see any error of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

### Using inline style with setAttribute()

I assume you are trying to remove the styling for display from `none`. `''` => *nothing* would not be a valid style to use, use a valid *property value* recognized by the **display** property, like `inline` or `block` for example.

You can override the **!important** rule set in CSS with the same CSS *hack* used in inline style as inline style takes presidence over styles set in CSS sheet. The only way I was able to do it was by setting the **style** attribute using `el.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline !important;')`. See snippit and a few examples of failure and finally success below...

```js
let dontUseImportant = document.querySelectorAll('#thing .x')

dontUseImportant.forEach(el => {
  // style display inline !important is ignored
  // this is likely a rule in JS that will disallow
  // spaces in values passed into properties for style
  // more research on this may be fruitful
  // however note the outcome in console.log
  el.style.display = "inline !important";  
  el.textContent = 'this will not parse to DOM'
  console.log(el)
})

dontUseImportant.forEach(el => {
  // style display is added but is over written by !important used in CSS
  el.style.display = "inline";  
  el.textContent = 'this will not parse to DOM'
  console.log(el)
})

// this also will not work 
dontUseImportant.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('style', 'display: null !important;');
  el.textContent = 'this will not parse to DOM'
  console.log(el)
})

// by adding !important using setAttribute behind our 
// property, this affects the elements style
// however, we are putting a bandaid on a bandaid
dontUseImportant.forEach(el => {
  el.setAttribute('style', 'display: inline !important;');
  el.textContent = 'content x is finally shown!'
  console.log(el)
})
```

```css
#thing .x {
  display: none !important;
}

.y {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thing">
  <div id="a">content a
    <span class="x">content x
      </span>
  </div>
  <div id="b">content b
    <span class="x">content x
      </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

### Swapping classes on element

Because the CSS file is using `!important` this unfortunately will override any styles you place on the element using `el.style.property = ''` regardless of using JS or a JS library like JQuery.

You could add a new class using JS that has a defining `display: inline` and then remove the old class. Keep in mind that you must add a valid property value when using styles. `display = ''` is not valid.

Your particular issue is a great example as to why `!important` is a ***BAD IDEA*** for styling as a crutch!

```js
let $dontUseImportant = $('#thing .x')
// iterate over elements and swap out the classes
// make sure to add the new class 'y' first 
// then remove initial class 'x'
$.each($dontUseImportant, function(i){
  $(this).addClass('y')
  $(this).removeClass('x')
  console.log($dontUseImportant[i])
})
```

```css
#thing .x {
    display: none !important;
}

.y {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thing">
   <div id="a">content a
      <span class="x" >content x
      </span>
   </div>
   <div id="b">content b
      <span class="x">content x
      </span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the `hidden` attribute? It is supported in all modern browsers. So in your case, you don't even need CSS.

**jQuery:**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('.x').each(function() {
    $(this).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thing">
  <div id="a">
    <span class="x" hidden>
      1
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <span class="x" hidden>
      2
    </span>
  </div>
</form>

<button>Show</button>
```

**Vanilla JS**

```js
const x = document.querySelectorAll('.x');
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  for (let item of x) {
    item.removeAttribute('hidden');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="thing">
  <div id="a">
    <span class="x" hidden>
      1
    </span>
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    <span class="x" hidden>
      2
    </span>
  </div>
</form>

<button>Show</button>
```